# PHP - how to send variable values without Global variables between php files?

Tags: php

Without use of cookie, session, post, get superglobals,  is there a way to retrieve variables between php files?

**1.php** has

```
$value="hello";
```

and

**2.php** wants to retrieve

```
$value // with value hello
```

Comment: Could save it in a file, perhaps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using a class...

**1.php**

```
<?php
  class Config {
      public static $test = "hello world!";
      public static $arrayTest = array(
         'var1'=>'hello',
         'var2'=>'world',
     );
}

?>
```

**2.php**

```
<?php
  include('1.php');
  echo Config::$test;
  echo Config::$arrayTest['var1'];
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**TRY this:**
1.php

```
$a="this is my 1.php";
```

2.php

```
include("1.php");
echo $a;
```

OUTPUT:

```
this is my 1.php
```

Comment: @mistysnake : it will surely work :) Did you try this?

Comment: This is the answer if you mean your php file is the one page.  If you mean separate calls as in the main index.php then retrieving images via another php script you must use those things you don't want - by cookie or URI ($_GET)

Comment: @EkriirkE : He wanted to access a variable from other php page in another php page. It should work that simply :)

Comment: THat's why I clarified (I thought) that the calling php is only 1 script file and they're using other php files within the 1 php load vs. the main page php and then another php script being loaded by any generated tags with a SRC=. e.g. index.php creates <HTML><IMG SRC="img.php"></HTML>, if they wanted to pass a variable to img.php from index.php they need to use cookies, $_GET or if it is a constant then an intermediary.php file shared by the two scripts by include().

Comment: @mistysnake wants variable value Without use of cookie, session, post, get superglobals. There are no other condition :) @ EkriirkE

Comment: Right, and with the second scenario I posted this is not possible ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a common method I use, because you can write to it as well, making it dynamic and not hard coded values that require you to manually edit the file.

globalvalues.php

```
<?
return array (
    'value1' => 'Testing'
);
```

2.php

```
$globalValues = include('globalvalues.php');

echo $globalValues['value1'];
```

I have wrapper classes around this, but thats the basics of it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the state of the variables somewhere.  If you don't want to use the session, you can write them to a file or database.  Or, you can store them client-side using JavaScript.  You can't read between two different requests without storing the information, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class, then include the class and reference the variables through that class.

Answer (score 0):

If they are run in the same call, then you can include the PHP file that defines the variable in the second PHP file and access it as if it was defined in the second one.

If these scripts are executed as part of 2 different calls, then you need to give us more information about what / why you are trying to do.